# Как брать 1 фрагмент из базы данных Python Sqlite3 (Для Aiogram бота)

Tags: python, база-данных, aiogram, sqlite3, бот

всем!
Хотел бы задать вопрос про использование библеотеки sqlite3 в python.

Я разрабатываю телеграмм бота на библеотеки aiogram, и мне нужно было создать базу данных, для хранения в ней товаров. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что я не могу брать и отправлять только что созданный объект из базы данных в телеграмм канал.

И тут я не пойму, проблема то ли в том, что бот не может отправлять сообщения в тг каналы, то ли в том, что бот не умеет брать 1 фрагмент базы данных...

коды:

база данных:

```
import sqlite3 as sq
from create_bot import bot
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
import logging

def sql_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('pizza_cool.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base connect OK!')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT, price TEXT)')
    base.commit()


async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()


async def sql_read(message):
    # for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
        # await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
        await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM menu WHERE name == ?', (message,))
    base.commit()
```

Код для внесения товаров в БД:

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from create_bot import dp, bot
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from data_base import sqlite_db
from KeyBoards import admin_cb
import logging
import sqlite3 as sq


ID = None
CHANNEL_ID = None

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    photo = State()
    name = State()
    description = State()
    price = State()

# def sql_start():
#     global base, cur
#     base = sq.connect('pizza_cool.db')
#     cur = base.cursor()
#     if base:
#         print('Data base connect OK!')
#     base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT, price TEXT)')
#     base.commit()
#
#
# async def sql_add_command(state):
#     async with state.proxy() as data:
#         cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
#         base.commit()
#
# async def sql_read(message):
#     for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
#         await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')

# @dp.message_handler(commands=['moderator'], id_chat_admin=True)
async def make_changes_command(message: types.Message):
    global ID
    ID = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'чего?') #reply_markup=admin_cb.button_case_admin
    logger.debug('the ansver is %r', message.text)

# @dp.message_handler(commands = 'load', state = None)
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        await FSMAdmin.photo.set()
        await message.reply('Ну ладно, Кидай фотки')

# @dp.message_handler(content_types = ['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Название?')

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.name)
async def load_name(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['name'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Введите описание')

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.description)
async def load_description(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['description'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Укажите цену')

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.price)
async def load_price(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['price'] = message.text
        await sqlite_db.sql_add_command(state)
        await state.finish()
# async def chouse_chat(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
#     if message.from_user.id == ID:
#         async with state.proxy() as data:
#             data['chat'] = message.text
#             if message.text == 'ткань':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001597797251'
#             if message.text == 'дет.обувь':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001625608148'
#             if message.text == 'муж.обувь':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001631330199'
#             if message.text == 'жен.обувь':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001572127086'
#             if message.text == 'дет.одежда':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001572740339'
#             if message.text == 'муж.одежда':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001791735254'
#             if message.text == 'жен.одежда':
#                 CHANNEL_ID = '-1001725156351'




# @dp.message_handler(state = "*", commands = 'exit')
# @dp.message_handler(Text(equals='exit', ignore_case=True), state="*")



async def cancel_handler(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        current_state = await state.get_state()
        if current_state is None:
            return
        await state.finish()
        await message.reply('ok')

def register_handler_admin(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, commands = ['загрузить'], state = None)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_photo, content_types = ['photo'], state = FSMAdmin.photo)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_name, state = FSMAdmin.name)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_description, state = FSMAdmin.description)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_price, state = FSMAdmin.price)
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, state='*', commands = 'cancel')
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')
    dp.register_message_handler(make_changes_command, commands = ['moderator'], is_chat_admin=True)
```

Простите, я пока что джун, и коды могут быть очень запутанными, но умоляю помогите, я уже неделю мучаюсь.....

а сейчас я в школу, так что

ЗАРАНЕЕ БЛАГОДАРЮ!

P.S. Есть и другие коды, если нужно будет что то посмотреть напишите, я отвечу, но только после 17-18(по МСК), я в школе буду

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас функция def sql_read нигде не вызывается, соответственно и отправки сообщения не будет. Её можно вызвать в отдельном хендлере. Например:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['/пример команды'])
async def read(message: types.Message)
    await sqlite_db.sql_read(message)
```

В переменной ret, в цикле for у Вас кортеж. К конкретному значению можно обратиться по индексу.

```
await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0]) # 0 - нужный Вам индекс
```

Это если я правильно понял, что именно Вам нужно.

Comment: спасибо, но бот должен кидать форму, а не просто фото

А когда пытаюсь отправлять ret[1]+ то не получаеться, пишет: 'name ret ret is not defined'

Всё равно спасибо!)

Comment: О какой форме идёт речь, можно чуть подробнее. И функцию или цикл, по которому выдаёт ошибку с переменной. Не видя кода сложно сказать почему именно  "имя не определено".